# Where do I make mistake on this derivative containing e^x^2

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

My brother is preparing for the university and asked me the following multiple choice question.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^3 * e^{x^2})$$

- a)  $e^{x^2}*x^2*(1+2x)$
- b)  $e^{x^2}*x^2*(3+2x)$
- c)  $e^{x^2}*x^2*(3+2x^2)$
- d)  $e^{x^2}*x^2*(3-2x)$
- e)  $e^{x^2}*x^2*(3-2x^2)$

Even though I find $e^{x^2}*x^2*(3+2x^2)$, the answer is $e^{x^2}*x^2*(3+2x)$. I wonder where do I make the mistake. What I did is as follows:

By product rule:

$$(x^3 * e^{x^2})' \Rightarrow 3x^2 * e^{x^2} + x^3 * (e^{x^2})'$$
Since $(e^{x^2})' = 2x * e^{x^2}$, the equation becomes 
$$3x^2 * e^{x^2} + x^3 * 2x * e^{x^2}$$
$$e^{x^2} * x^2 * (3 + 2x^2)$$

Thanks

Comment: You are right. The "answer" is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that super quick reply

Comment: You can use WA to check that you're right: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx%5E3+exp(x%5E2)%2Cx%5D

Comment: @DavidMitra As a quick check, the original function is an odd function, therefore the derivative would be expected to be an even function - useful in multi-choice like this as it eliminates some answers quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm writing this just to show a possibility.

If $e^{x^2}$ represents $(e^x)^2$ *in the textbook*, **which should be written as $e^{2x}$**, then the answer is $(e^x)^2\cdot x^2\cdot (3+2x)$.

(By the way, since $e^{x^2}$ means $e^{(x^2)}$ in general, your calculation has no mistakes.)

Comment: Very good point. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CahitGungor: You are welcome. I'm glad to help you.